# SSL Socket over socks proxy - Is client <---> server data encrypted?

Tags: ssl, proxy, socks

I am using the following java code to create a ssl socket over socks proxy.

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxy_ip, prox_port);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
Socket plainSocket = new Socket(proxy);
InetSocketAddress dest = new InetSocketAddress(server_ip, 443);
plainSocket.connect(dest);
socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(plainSocket, config.getApiHost(), config.getApiPort(), true);
socket.startHandshake();
```

This code works; but I am not sure if client to proxy data is encrypted or not. In wireshark I see that only data between proxy and server is encrypted. Can anyone tell, why this is the case and how can we encrypt data between client and proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOCKS by itself does not encrypt anything nor does it break any encryption. All it does is forwarding the data between client and target server without any changes. Thus, if your data is encrypted already it will stay so. If it was not encrypted then it will be open for sniffing and modification since SOCKS does not add any protection to the transfer.

In your specific case you are using SSL inside the SOCKS connection which means that the application data will be encrypted the same way as without SOCKS proxy: if you use SSL properly (strong ciphers, proper server authentication) it will  also be strongly protected when using a SOCKS proxy. If instead you fail in doing SSL correctly (like not validating the servers certificate properly) SOCKS will not help to protect the data. Instead the operator of the SOCKS server might in this case easily man-in-the-middle your insecure SSL connection since he is alreafy in the right position in the network to do this.

Comment: But in the wireshark, I only see TLSV1.2 packet going between proxy and the server. The application data is shown to be encrypted. But between the client and the proxy, I see TCP packet going, which has a data field, which is unencrypted. I am using charless proxy for SOCKS Server.

Comment: @user3202934: You see TLS 1.2 messages because you are using TLS "inside" the SOCKS connection. The SOCKS connection is actually only some initial data on the connection to let the proxy know where to connect and maybe authentication. After this handshake the original (TLS) messages are sent and that's why they can be seen in wireshark too.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** The SOCKS handshake is not encrypted. After the upstream connection is established, the SSL handshake occurs between your code and the upstream peer, and SSL is end-to-end from there on. The SOCKS proxy doesn't know what's going through it.

Comment: I dont see any CONNECT packet in wireshark. The data I send is some custom data (NOT HTTP).